# Sagemaker Keras Output to csv

Tags: keras, amazon-sagemaker

My input is a csv file: No header, the first column is id, the rest is features

I'm using keras to predict for a result with 4 varible. I want associate it with the original ID.

My last layer of keras looks like: model.add(Dense(4, activation='linear'))

My output without ID looks like this:
(I believe it's not in csv format.)

```
{
    "predictions": [[1.23, 1.34, 2.42, 1.80], ...]
}
```

This seems weired and I cannot even join with the input.

Any idea on it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide an "inference.py" script as entry_point of the the Model class and save your prediction output to a csv file.

Here's instructions on how to use Pre/Post-Processing:

https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-tensorflow-serving-container#prepost-processing